# Unable to access application on Websphere 8.5.5.1 from remote machine

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I have installed Websphere 8.5.5.1 on Linux Machine. Following are the details :

```
product = WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.1
wlp.install.dir = /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/
java.home = /root/Downloads/jre1.6.0_45
java.version = 1.6.0_45
java.runtime = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (1.6.0_45-b06)
os = Linux (2.6.32-431.23.3.el6.x86_64; amd64) (en_US)
```

I am able to access my application on server through url `http://hostIP:9080/context` from the machine in which server is installed. However, I am `not able to access` the same url from other machine. Following is the entry in server.cml file:

```
<httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint">       
    <tcpOptions soReuseAddr="true"/>
</httpEndpoint>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have probably some firewall blocking access.

Comment: It does the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be firewall or some network issue. if working locally it should work from remote server.